# Large Number Issues in C++

Tags: c++, long-integer

I'm working on a relatively simple  problem based around adding all the primes under a certain value together. I've written a program that should accomplish this task. I am using long type variables. As I get up into higher numbers (~200/300k), the variable I am using to track the sum becomes negative despite the fact that no negative values are being added to it (based on my knowledge and some testing I've done). Is there some issue with the data type or I am missing something.

My code is below (in C++) [Vector is basically a dynamic array in case people are wondering]:

```
bool checkPrime(int number, vector<long> & primes, int numberOfPrimes) {
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfPrimes-1; i++) {
        if(number%primes[i]==0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

long solveProblem10(int maxNumber) {
    long sumOfPrimes=0;
    vector<long> primes;
    primes.resize(1);
    int numberOfPrimes=0;
    for (int i=2; i<maxNumber; i++) {
        if(checkPrime(i, primes, numberOfPrimes)) {
            sumOfPrimes=sumOfPrimes+i;
            primes[numberOfPrimes]=long(i);
            numberOfPrimes++;
            primes.resize(numberOfPrimes+1);
        }
    }
    return sumOfPrimes;
}
```

Comment: Integer overflow. It's always integer overflow. :)

Answer (score 3):

Integers represent values use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) which means that the highest order bit represents the sign.  When you add the number up high enough, the highest bit is set (an [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)) and the number becomes negative.

You can resolve this by using an `unsigned long` (32-bit, and may still overflow with the values you're summing) or by using an `unsigned long long` (which is 64 bit).

Answer (score 2):

> the variable I am using to track the sum becomes negative despite the fact that no negative values are being added to it (based on my knowledge and some testing I've done)

longs are signed integers. In C++ and other lower-level languages, integer types have a fixed size. When you add past their maximum they will overflow and wrap-around to negative numbers. This is due to the behavior of how [twos complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works.

Answer (score 0):

`long` is probably only 32 bits on your system - use `uint64_t` for the sum - this gives you a guaranteed 64 bit unsigned integer.

```
#include <cstdint>

uint64_t sumOfPrimes=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

check valid integer values: [Variables. Data Types.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)

you're using `signed long`, which is usually 32 bit, which means -2kkk - 2kkk, you can either use `unsigned long`, which is 0-4kkk, or use 64 bit `(un)signed long long`

if you need values bigger 2^64 (unsigned long long), you will need to use [bignum math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)

Answer (score 0):

You can include header `<cstdint>` and use type std::uintmax_t instead of long.